# Dependency inject a class that has a dependency injection form DbContext

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

How can I inject this:

```
private readonly CarModelsController _carModelsController;

public AdminController(CarModelsController carModelsController)
{
    _carModelsController = carModelsController;
}
```

When the CarModelsController looks like this:

```
[ApiController]
    public class CarModelsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public CarModelsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
```

I need to have the DbContext when I inject it? Should it be done in another way? What's the correct way to go here? I've never learned this.

Comment: register all dependencies with the DI container at startup in the composition root.

Comment: How is that done?

Comment: I am more curios about why are you injecting one controller into another?

Comment: How are you registering your controller? You need to follow same syntax for DBContext.

Comment: @Nkosi I have all my Db actions in that controller. 

What do you mean? Wich model? And what syntax are u talking about? :P

Comment: @Charlie documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#replacing-the-default-services-container but I would advise you review the choice of injecting controllers into each other. create a service class that hold the Db actions and inject that into your controllers.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise you review the choice of injecting controllers into each other.

Create a service abstraction and class that holds the Db related actions

```
public interface IDataService {
    //...expose desired members
}

public class DataService: IDataService {
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;

    public DataService(ApplicationDbContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    //...other members implemented
}
```

and inject that into your controllers.

```
public class AdminController: ControllerBase {    
    private readonly IDataService service;

    public AdminController(IDataService service) {
        this.service = service
    }

    //...
}

[ApiController]
public class CarModelsController : ControllerBase  
    private readonly IDataService service;

    public CarModelsController(IDataService service) {
        this.service = service
    }

    //...
}
```

All that is left is to register all dependencies with the DI container at startup in the composition root.

Assuming default .Net Core DI

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(...);
services.AddScoped<IDataService, DataService>();
```

Reference [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Answer (score 0):

You nedd to inject your dependencies into the startup class ConfigureServices method.

```
 public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services) {

        services.AddScoped<DbContext, Your_Project_DbContext> ();
        services.AddScoped<Your_Interface, Your_Concrete_Class> ();
    }
```